# Orbeon Forms - upgrade

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to upgrade my orbeon forms (which are used in a internal application called EZD) to new ones but after switching configs from old to new in : **( WEB-INF/resources/config/properties-local.xml, WEB-INF/resources/config/form-builder-permissions.xml, WEB-INF/resources/config/log4j.xml and WEB-INF/web.xml )**
but get all the time this message:

[image]

Which files should I actually move from my original WEB-INF folder to the new one?

Comment: It's possible that web.xml is the culprit. Keep the new web.xml, and carefully merge over to the new web.xml any changes to the standard web.xml you might have had with the older version. Also, check the Tomcat logs and Orbeon logs for any errors.